# Make ispell automatically clear minibuffer when replacing word

Tags: spell-checking

When using [ispell](http://fmg-www.cs.ucla.edu/geoff/ispell.html) to check spelling and encountering an incorrect word, pressing `r` takes you to the minibuffer where you can enter a replacement for the misspelled word. By default the minibuffer already contains the incorrectly spelled word and so I need to clear the minibuffer first before being able to type in the replacement.

**How do I add a hook to clear the input prompt automatically?**

Comment: I see I can edit the source ispell.el and change line 2358 `(read-string "Replacement for: " word nil)` to `(read-string "Replacement for: " nil nil)` which is a bit of a hack, but does work. Having a limited knowledge of emacs and ispell, I would prefer something I can stick in my .emacs file :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, I don't know if this is a good way to solve this issue, but it works (though fragile) and it shows a method that is applicable in other case.

Test case (since the Young Grandfather (*tYG)* forgot to post one):

```
(with-temp-buffer
  (setq ispell-program-name "hunspell")
  (switch-to-buffer (current-buffer))
  (insert "speling")
  (ispell-word))
```

You see what *tYG* talks about by evaluating and clicking `r`.
(Leave out the `hunspell` part if that's better for you).

Since `ispell-command-loop` is very complicated, it's not easy to mess with its internals.  But we can use a fragile advice around it, see [`(info "(elisp) Advising Functions")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html).  Note that we are using Stefan Monnier's new, hip and super-nice `nadvice.el` package!

```
(defun rasmus/ispell-loop-get-rid-of-misspeled-word (orig-fun &rest args)
  "Around-advice to avoid the misspeled word when typing r in ispell."
  (require 'cl)
  (cl-letf* (((symbol-function #'read-string*) (symbol-function #'read-string))
     ((symbol-function #'read-string)
      (lambda (prompt &optional initial-input history default-value
             inherit-input-method)
        (if (equal prompt "Replacement for: ")
        (read-string* prompt)
          (read-string* prompt initial-input history default-value
                inherit-input-method)))))
(apply orig-fun args)))

(advice-add 'ispell-command-loop :around
    #'rasmus/ispell-loop-get-rid-of-misspeled-word)
```

Run the test again.  The misspelled word should be gone.

Bonus: do `C-h` `f` `ispell-command-loop` `C-j`.  It should contain a line like 
`` :around advice: `rasmus/ispell-loop-get-rid-of-misspeled-word' ``.

Comment: I'd edit your answer quickly if I were at a computer; misspeled is misspelled :)

Comment: Kaushlmodi, it's a homage to http://www.speling.org/.  In the context it works better, no!?

Comment: Excellent thanks very much will be using. Just did a copy and paste, all is working. Will get round to figuring out what you did at some other stage ...

Answer (score 2):

@rasmus provided a nice programmatic solution.  Here's another solution that is more interactive - it emulates what you manually do to clear the minibuffer when it's displayed with initial input:

```
(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook
          (lambda ()
            (when (equal (minibuffer-prompt) "Replacement for: ")
              (delete-minibuffer-contents))))
```

Comment: That's certainly nice and simple!  `r(z)grep` suggests that the string/prompt is unique (disregarding `site-lisp`), so I think it's pretty "safe" from false positives as well.